# Cpanel restore file code

Tags: cpanel

I am using CPANEL and there I edited and created my website directly.

I had php file with about 300 lines and somehow I changed encoding to something other than `utf-8`. When I changed it and saved it saved only first 10-20 lines of my file. I cannot redo (ctrl+z) to bring my code back.

So my question is how to get lost file back? I haven't closed it yet so session is still valid. Please fast help. I know I will get downvote but I am in despair....

Answer (score 0):

You may be lucky depending on backups...

If you go into the `Files` section and click `Backups`, then select the most recent backup where you know your file still existed in the correct state (before you made the encoding change).

If you then save the file and unzip it, hopefully your file will be there and you will be able to re-upload it. Good luck!

In future, definitely develop offline and use source control then upload copies of your file to avoid this.